# php login script not redirecting to next page

Tags: php

My login.php is as given below, It is not able to take me to welcome.php. Neither it is giving login error. It simply give 500 error page.

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
$password=md5($password); // Encrypted Password
$sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and passcode='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($db,$result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
header("location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form-signin" action="login.php" method="post">       
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please login</h2>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required="" autofocus="" />
</br> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>    
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   
    </form>
  </div>
```

It gives 500 error after I submit usename and password and not able to take me to welcome.php.

Comment: FYI, MD5 is *not encrypting the password. It's hashing it. Also, it's obsolete and not what you should be doing to store that password safely. You are also wide open to SQL injections. And you should turn on error reporting to see what PHP is reporting the error as.

Comment: How to show errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using header(Location: something.php), you should load it as first output in php. Or else it will not work.

`session_start()` will change the HTTP Header.

Instead try below one,

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='welcome.php';</script>";
```